# Como convertir un archivo de texto en una lista y separar los elementos segun el caracter

Tags: python, lista, txt

Estoy tratando de convertir un archivo de texto en
una lista donde pueda separar sus elementos para luego poder
"traducir" el valor de los parametros.

Cuento con un archivo de texto como el siguiente:

> 43;00000;1; 44;;1; 602;;1; 45;0;1; 877;00000;1; 46; 0020000;1; 47;
> 0019750;1; 48; 0020250;1; 49; 0005500;1;

El primer grupo de valores antes de la coma tienen un significado y el segundo grupo de numeros otro, me gustaria separarlos, para crear
una tabla donde pueda traducir dichos valores por ejemplo 43 = fuente.

Actualmente tengo este codigo donde identifico donde abro el archivo lo organizo y ubico el seprador en este caso ";" y me indica el indice
donde este caracrter se encuentra.

```
    import re
    
    fichero = open('C:\\nwparametersdata\ejemplo.txt')
    lineas = fichero.readlines()
    r = re.compile(r"(\d+)")  
    lineas.sort(key=lambda x: int(r.search(x).group(1)))
    print(lineas)
    print("--------------------------")
    print(lineas [0])
    print (len(lineas[0]))
    
    #BUSCAMOS DONDE ESTA EL SEPARADOR ";" EN EL CONTENEDOR 0
    
    separadores1 =([pos for pos, char in enumerate(lineas[0]) if char == ";"])
    print(separadores1)
```

Bien ahora me gustaria separar los valores antes y despues del ";"
para poder "traducir" esos valores a algo legible para el usuario final.

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Usa [str.split](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Reviendo tu pregunta, si estás trabajando con csvs te recomiendo evitar el uso de split, ya que esto no tiene en cuenta los ; dentro de las comillas. Es decir, esto '"a;b";c ' te quedaría como ['"a;','b"','c']. En su lugar usa el modulo de la biblioteca estandar [csv](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/csv.html)